# action decorator not calling method in DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

so I have a route api/reviews it works fine for basic CRUD operations but according to DRF documentation, I can add extra actions to post, put, patch requests by using the @action decorator.

the route is:
POST domain/api/reviews     data=irrelevent JSON

```
# reviews/<uuid:id> && reviews
# Provides CRUD + List interface for Reviews
class ReviewView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsPosterOrSafeOnly]
    queryset = Review.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer
    pagination_class = Pagination

    @action(detail=False, methods=['post','put', 'patch'], serializer_class=ReviewSerializer)
    def rating(self, request):
        print("100: ", request)
```

from what I understand the way this works is that when I do a post request to the reviews route it will do the post like it normally does and it will do the task in the action decorator.

so I tried doing a post request to see if the code inside the 'rating' method gets run and it does not. I have tried setting detail to both True and False including the pk. nothing really seems to work.

Comment: wouldn't the url be "domain/api/reviews/rating" otherwise it's just calling the `list` method of `ModelViewSet`

Comment: @JimmyPells Oh you are right it worked when I added /rating but the problem is the intended purpose for this is to work when any post or put request is made. I.e, when a post request is made the modelViewSet calls its default create method plus I want to call `rating` for a little bit of extra functionality. is this something that's possible? without having to put /rating?

Comment: You can override `create` and call `rating` there

Comment: def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("100: ", request)
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)